# ServiceBase.OnPowerEvent does not wait for service processing to complete

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, wmi

I have a third party service that does not behave correctly if the machine goes to sleep. Hence I wanted to stop the service before the machine goes to sleep. For that purpose I created a C# `Windows Service` that listens to `ServiceBase.OnPowerEvent` event and shuts the third party service.

The issue is that the service takes about 5-6 seconds to shutdown. The Sleep event comes, I start shutting down the third party service. However, before I complete my processing, the machine goes to sleep.

I tried using `Win32_PowerManagementEvent` class too as an alternate approach and that too does not wait for client processing to complete.

Is there a way to make the system wait for my processing to complete before it goes to sleep?

Comment: You are correct, I had the correct page at some point yesterday, but you are correct, what I posted is not the page. I'll repost when I find it.